# Show that $\mathcal{D}$ is a Dynkin-System (concerning transition measure)

Tags: measure-theory

In our lecture we had the following definition for "transition measure".

Let $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1), (\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_1)$ be two measurable spaces. A function $K\colon \Omega_1\times\mathcal{A}_2\to [0,\infty)$ is called transition measure from $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$ to $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2)$ if

(1) $A\mapsto K(\omega_1,A)$ is a measure on $\mathcal{A}_2$ for all $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$

(2) $\omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_1,A)$ is a $\mathcal{A}_1-\mathcal{B}$-measurable function for all $A\in\mathcal{A}_2$.

Now the following exercise is given:

> > Show that it is enough to claim the condition (2) in the definition of transition mesaure only for sets $A$ out of a generator $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{A}_2$ which is closed under intersections, because then (2) is achieved for all $A\in\mathcal{A}_2$.

I already had some thoughts about that and going through the script, I think the strategy is to show that 
$$
\mathcal{D}:=\left\{A\in\mathcal{A}_2: \omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_1,A)\text{ is }\mathcal{A}_1-\mathcal{B}-\text{measurable}\right\}
$$
is a Dynkin-System with $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{D}$. Because then it follows
$$
\mathcal{A}_2=\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\delta(\mathcal{C})\subset\mathcal{D},
$$
where $\delta(\mathcal{C})$ is the Dynkin-system generated by $\mathcal{C}$.

So far so good. But now I have problems to show that $\mathcal{D}$ is indeed a Dynkin-system.

There are three things to show in order to prove that $\mathcal{D}$ is a Dynkin-system:

(a) $\Omega_2\in\mathcal{D}$

(b) $A,B\in\mathcal{D}, A\subset B\implies B\setminus A\in\mathcal{D}$

(c) $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{D}$, pairwise disjoint $\implies \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal{D}$

Furthermore it is to show that

(d) $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{D}$.

---

As I said I have unexpected problems to show (a), (b), (c) and (d).

I start with (a) to show you what f.e. is my problem.

**(a)**

It is to show that $\omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_1,\Omega_2)$ is $\mathcal{A}_1-\mathcal{B}$-measurable. To do so i take f.e. $(-\infty, c]\in\mathcal{B}$ and I have to show that the preimage is in $\mathcal{A}_1$. But how can I do so?

With greetings

math12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You have to assume something in addition (as I will show below), such as $K(\cdot,\Omega)$ being constant, say when $K(\omega,\cdot)$ is always a probability measure.

b) You can write $K(\cdot,B\backslash A)$ as the difference of two measurable functions.

c) Pick some real number $r$. By assumption, $K(\omega,\cdot)$ is a measure for all $\Omega$. So the set of $\omega$ such that $K\Big(\omega,\bigcup_n A\Big)>r$ is the set of all $\omega$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty K(\omega,A_n)>r$, which equals the set of all $\omega$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N K(\cdot,A_n)>r$ for some $N$. Let $Q^n$ be the countable set of $n$-tuples of nonnegative rationals with sum larger than $r$. Let $E_N$ be the event that $\sum_{n=1}^N K(\cdot,A_n)>r$. We can write it as $$E_N=\bigcup_{(q_1,\ldots,q_N)\in Q^N}\bigg(K(\cdot,A_1)^{-1}\Big([q_1,\infty)\Big)\cap\ldots\cap K(\cdot,A_N)^{-1}\Big([q_N,\infty)\Big)\bigg),$$
which is clearly measurable. So the set of $\omega$ such that $K\Big(\omega,\bigcup_n A_n\Big)>r$ is $\bigcup_N E_N$, which is measurable. Since $r$ was arbitrary, we have proven this part.

d) Holds by assumption.

---

Here is an example where the result fails. Let $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$ be a measurable space that contains a nonmeasurable subset $N$. Let $\Omega_2$ be nonempty and let $\mathcal{A_2}=\{\Omega_2,\emptyset\}$. We can take $\mathcal{C}=\emptyset$ here, so that (2) holds for all sets in $\mathcal{C}$ vacuously. Now a measure on $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2$ is determined by the measure assigned to $\Omega_2$. So let $K(\omega,\Omega_2)=1$ for $\omega\in N$ and $K(\omega,\Omega_2)=2$ for $\omega\notin N$. Then $\omega\to K(\omega,\Omega_2)$ is not measurable.

Comment: Let's see if I got it, f.e. (b). When I got it right I have f.e. to assume that $A\mapsto K(\omega_1, A)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}_2$ for all $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$. Then $\omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_1,B\setminus A)=K(\omega_1,B)-K(\omega_1,A)$, because $K(\omega_1, B\setminus A)$ is a probability measure and $K(\omega_1,A)<\infty$. And by assumption, $\omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_i,B)$ and $\omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_1,A)$ are measurable.

Comment: But why is it necessary to make the additional assumption, that $K(\cdot,\Omega)$ constant? Isn't it enough, that $K(\omega_1,\Omega_2)<\infty$?

Comment: @math12 All you have to assume is that $K(\omega,)$ is a finite measure. Then since $A\subseteq B$, $K(\omega,B)=K(\omega, A\cup B\backslash A)=K(\omega,A)+K(\omega,B\backslash A)$. Hence, $K(\omega, B\backslash A)=K(\omega,B)-K(\omega,A)$.

Comment: Yes, but I do not have to assume that, because by definition it is $K\colon\Omega_1\times\mathcal{A}_2\to [0,\infty)$, so $K(\omega_1,\Omega_2)$ cannot be $\infty$.

Comment: @math12 At the bottom of my answer is an  example that shows the problem cannot be solved without an additional asumption, $K(\cdot,\Omega_2)$ being one sufficient condition for the problem to be solvable.

Comment: @math12 Yes, that is already in the assumptions.

Comment: Ok, I understood your answer in that way that the exercise lacks an assumption.

Comment: @math12 It does, but the lack of this assumption doesn't matter for (b)-(d), only for (a).

Comment: Ok, I think now I see your point! And with that assumtion (a) is very easy: Then $\omega_1\mapsto K(\omega_1,\Omega_2)$ (maybe better written as $K(\cdot,\Omega_2)$ to make really clear that the first argument is variable) is a constant function and therefore $\mathcal{A}_1-\mathcal{B}$-measurable.

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: What I do not really understand is the following part out of your proof of (c): "[...] the set of all $\omega$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}K(\omega,A_n)>r$ which equals the set of all $\omega$ sucht that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}K(\cdot,A_n)>r$ for some $N$."

Comment: @math12 The value of the series is the limit of the partial sums. If the limit is larger than $r$, so must be (since it is nondecreasing) all partial sums from one index onwards.

Comment: Okay, so there are the events $E_N, E_{N+1},\ldots$ and for each $E_m, m\geq N$ one can write it as you did by the help of the tupel. And in the end one has to union the $E_m, m\geq N$ because all this events together are those $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}K(\omega_1,\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)>r$?

Comment: @math12 Yes, that's true.

Comment: Ok, then I got the idea. Took a while, sorry. And (d) is because the assumption is that (2) holds for $A$ out of $\mathcal{C}$. So those are in $\mathcal{D}$ naturally, there is nothing to show. Right?

Comment: @math12 Yes, indeed.